# AppModule.XXXX is Undefined NestJS

Tags: configuración, undefined, nestjs, module.exports, environment

Estoy creando un modulo de configuraciones para englobar de una mejor manera las variables de entorno pero no puedo usarlas en otros modules que no sean el AppModule

```
export class AppModule {


static URL_BASE: string
  static TM_API_KEY: string
  static URI_TM: string
  static PORT: number | string
  static SENGRID_API_KEY: string
  static TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID: string
  static TWILIO_API_KEY: string
  static TWILIO_API_SECRET: string
  static TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER: string
  static SURFING_URL_BASE: string
  static RI_URL_BASE: string



constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {

AppModule.URL_BASE = this.configService.get<string>(Configuration.URL_BASE)
AppModule.TM_API_KEY = this.configService.get<string>(Configuration.TM_API_KEY)
AppModule.URI_TM = this.configService.get<string>(Configuration.URI_TM)
AppModule.PORT = this.configService.get<string>(Configuration.PORT)
AppModule.SENGRID_API_KEY = this.configService.get<string>(Configuration.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
AppModule.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = this.configService.get<string>(Configuration.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID)
AppModule.TWILIO_API_KEY = this.configService.get<string>(Configuration.TWILIO_API_KEY)
AppModule.TWILIO_API_SECRET = this.configService.get<string>(Configuration.TWILIO_API_SECRET)
AppModule.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER = this.configService.get<string>(Configuration.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER)
AppModule.SURFING_URL_BASE = this.configService.get<string>(Configuration.SURFING_URL_BASE)
AppModule.RI_URL_BASE = this.configService.get<string>(Configuration.RI_URL_BASE)

console.log(AppModule)
  }
```

**Constructor de otro modulo**

```
constructor() {
console.log(AppModule.PORT)
```

}

> Devuelve `undefined`

El primer console.log() donde se muestra el AppModule si muestra la información completa pero al pasar a otro modulo y llamar a las variables estaticas de AppModule no me devuelve ningun resultado

Answer (score 0):

Echale una mirada al módulo Config de Nestjs https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration ahí explican muy buen como levantar variables de entorno. Un poco más abajo en ese documento, te explican como encapsularlas programaticamente, o sea por codigo y no por archivo de configuración. Me cuentas como te va

Answer (score 0):

Le muestro un ejemplo de una app en producción, quizás le aclare más como realizarlo.

`app.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as Joi from 'joi';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: `.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`,
      validationSchema: Joi.object({
        HOST: Joi.string().required(),
        DATABASE: Joi.string().required(),
        PORT: Joi.string().required(),
        DOMAIN: Joi.string().required(),
        JWT_SECRET: Joi.string().required(),
        JWT_EXPIRATION_TIME: Joi.string().required(),
      }),
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

El paquete `Joi` se usa para validaciones. Vea además `envFilePath` es el fichero de variables de entorno, el cual lleva el nombre dependiendo del entorno en el que usted se encuentre por ejemplo `.developed.env` para desarrollo y `.production.env` para producción.

Ahora le muestro como usarlo desde sus otros servicios.

`resource.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Injectable()
export class ResourceService{
const urlBase: string = this.configService.get('DOMAIN');
  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService,
  ) {}
```

`resource.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
  ],
  controllers: [ResourceController],
  providers: [ResourceService],
  exports: [ResourceService],
})
export class PalomarModule {}
```

Y esto es todo. Usted puede mejorarlo a su gusto.

Espero sea de ayuda.